# Как извлечь данные из массива?

Tags: java, android, массивы, json

У меня есть JSON файл. Mне нужно извлечь из него элемент массива и превратить его в объект.

JSON файл:

```
{
    "coord":{
        "lon":24.0232,
        "lat":49.8383
    },
    "weather":[
        {
            "id":800,
            "main":"Clear",
            "description":"чисте небо",
            "icon":"01d"
        }
    ],
    "base":"stations",
    "main":{
        "temp":8.74,
        "feels_like":6.45,
        "temp_min":8.33,
        "temp_max":9,
        "pressure":1011,
        "humidity":40
    },
    "visibility":10000,
    "wind":{
        "speed":4,
        "deg":350
    },
    "clouds":{
        "all":0
    },
    "dt":1617448518,
    "sys":{
        "type":1,
        "id":8909,
        "country":"UA",
        "sunrise":1617422174,
        "sunset":1617469065
    },
    "timezone":10800,
    "id":702550,
    "name":"Lviv",
    "cod":200
}
```

Нужно извлечь `description`.

```
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray ar=(JSONArray) jo.get("weather");

result_info.setText("Температура: "+jo.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp")+"\n"
             +"мін Температура: "+jo.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("feels_like")+"\n"
             +"Хмарність: "+ar.getString(2));
```

Это мой вариант, но он не работает.

Comment: а у вас в чем именно проблема возникла?

Comment: именно это не работает ar.getString(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

извлекает из массива

`JSONArray jsonArray = jo.getJSONArray("weather"); JSONObject jsonWeather = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); jsonWeather.getString("description");`

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы лезете в дебри? С помощью любого онлайн сервиса превращаем джейсов в класс джава. Берем нормальный сериализатор (максимально простой в использовании). Заталкиваем в него джейсон, подставляя заранее подготовленный класс, получаем объект. Все!

```
import java.util.List;

@lombok.Data
public class Root {

    public Coord coord;
    public List<Weather> weather;
    public String base;
    public Main main;
    public Integer visibility;
    public Wind wind;
    public Clouds clouds;
    public Integer dt;
    public Sys sys;
    public Integer timezone;
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public Integer cod;

    @lombok.Data
    public static class Coord {
        public Double lon;
        public Double lat;
    }

    @lombok.Data
    public static class Weather {

        public Integer id;
        public String main;
        public String description;
        public String icon;
    }

    @lombok.Data
    public static class Main {

        public Double temp;
        public Double feels_like;
        public Double temp_min;
        public Integer temp_max;
        public Integer pressure;
        public Integer humidity;
    }

    @lombok.Data
    public static class Wind {

        public Integer speed;
        public Integer deg;
    }

    @lombok.Data
    public static class Clouds {

        public Integer all;
    }

    @lombok.Data
    public static class Sys {

        public Integer type;
        public Integer id;
        public String country;
        public Integer sunrise;
        public Integer sunset;
    }

}

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@lombok.Data
public class Weather {

    private Double temp;
    private Double tempMin;
    private String humidity;

    public static Weather ofRoot(Root root) {
        Weather result = new Weather();
        result.temp = root.getMain().getTemp();
        result.tempMin = root.getMain().getFeels_like();
        result.humidity = root.getWeather().stream()
                .map(Root.Weather::getDescription).collect(Collectors.joining("; "));
        return result;
    }

}


import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Parser {
    
    private final static Gson GSON = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String json = "{\n" +
"    \"coord\":{\n" +
"        \"lon\":24.0232,\n" +
"        \"lat\":49.8383\n" +
"    },\n" +
"    \"weather\":[\n" +
"        {\n" +
"            \"id\":800,\n" +
"            \"main\":\"Clear\",\n" +
"            \"description\":\"чисте небо\",\n" +
"            \"icon\":\"01d\"\n" +
"        }\n" +
"    ],\n" +
"    \"base\":\"stations\",\n" +
"    \"main\":{\n" +
"        \"temp\":8.74,\n" +
"        \"feels_like\":6.45,\n" +
"        \"temp_min\":8.33,\n" +
"        \"temp_max\":9,\n" +
"        \"pressure\":1011,\n" +
"        \"humidity\":40\n" +
"    },\n" +
"    \"visibility\":10000,\n" +
"    \"wind\":{\n" +
"        \"speed\":4,\n" +
"        \"deg\":350\n" +
"    },\n" +
"    \"clouds\":{\n" +
"        \"all\":0\n" +
"    },\n" +
"    \"dt\":1617448518,\n" +
"    \"sys\":{\n" +
"        \"type\":1,\n" +
"        \"id\":8909,\n" +
"        \"country\":\"UA\",\n" +
"        \"sunrise\":1617422174,\n" +
"        \"sunset\":1617469065\n" +
"    },\n" +
"    \"timezone\":10800,\n" +
"    \"id\":702550,\n" +
"    \"name\":\"Lviv\",\n" +
"    \"cod\":200\n" +
"}";

        //вариант 1 : получаем все поля description , итерируясь по вложенной коллекции
        Root root = GSON.fromJson(json, Root.class);
        for (Root.Weather weather: root.getWeather()) {
            String description = weather.getDescription();
        }
        
        //вариант 2 : пишем класс с полями, которые нам необходимы для использования и используем его
        Weather weather = Weather.ofRoot(GSON.fromJson(json, Root.class));
        System.out.println(weather);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: могли бы объяснить что здесь делается и как извлечь конкретный элемент не совсем понимаю

Comment: нужно писать столько кода чтобы извлечь 1 элемент?

Comment: вроде уже описал... простите, сколько кода?  Root root = new Gson().fromJson(json, Root.class); это все, что вам нужно написать. остальное - либо исходный джейсон, либо автогенерируемый из этого джейсона код. просто я даю вам вопроизводимый пример, чтобы исключить потенциальные вопросы

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
    Root root = gson.fromJson(result, Root.class);
    result_info.setText(root.weather.toString(description));

Comment: как вытянуть данные из объекта description
так как я написал description отображается красным

Comment: @robot ответ изменил. ваш  экземпляр класса Root root содержит коллекцию типа Weather,а не объект типа Weather. Посему получаем геттером, крутим в цикле, берем нужные поля, к примеру, description... все, как в ответе

Comment: @robot второй вариант также показан и помечен соответсвующим комментарием. класс-дто, кторый необходим для того, чтобы спарсить джейсон (Root), оставляем в покое в соответствии с принципом единой ответсенности. создаем новые класс(Weather) с полями и методами, которые нам нужны и используем их. ну и , разумеется, пишем метод, который достанет данные из объекта Root и сложит их в удобный нам объект Weather

Comment: for (Root.Weather weather : root.getWeather()) {
                result_info.setText(  weather.getDescription()я написал так и оно выводит нужную информацию только для одного города для других городов приложение закрывается

Comment: @robot это ваше приложение. почему оно закрывается, не работет, странно себя ведет и т.д. я ответить не могу, т.к. не обладаю экстрасенсорными способностями. я лишь отвечаю на поставленный вопрос. а он состоит в том, чтобы спарить предоставленный джейсон